# Why does my laptop shows 2 monitors on the EDID record?

Tags: display

I'm using this small utility to extract information from my HP laptop's monitor: [MonitorInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/monitor_info_view.html)

Apparently, it says I have two monitors registered on the [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) records, one of 1280 X 800 and 60 Hz (this one is the active one), and another of 1680 X 1050 and 60 Hz (unactive).

[image]

Why is it, if I have no extenal monitor around? And is there any chance I can work with the bigger resolution?

Windows Vista, by its side, doesn't seem to recognize the 1680 resolution monitor on the display settings.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: What laptop do you have?

Comment: Your laptop probably supports dual displays -- one being built in, and the other being plugged into the external monitor port. (That is, in addition to cloning the internal display to the external, you can probably use them as two separate displays.) Try activating dual-display mode, by whatever method your laptop offers to do so, and see if the listing for the 1680x1050 display changes to "active" in MonitorInfoView.